# How to add more columns to datagridview bounded form DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

I have bounded data to `datatable` and then I have set the `datatable` as datasource for the `datagridview` now I want to know

1. How to add two more columns for the `datagridview` first one of type `button` and the second `checkbox`
2. How to set the order of this two column ?

I searched and found that I have to add them after binding the data and not directly to `datatable` but on the `datagridview`

3. another question can I add columns from `datatable` to specific column in the 
   already created `datagridview`

   ```
   public DataTable GetMyList()
   {
       string Count;
       string cmdStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString();
       string cmdStr = @"SELECT column1,
                                column2,
                                column3
                          FROM Table_Name
                         ORDER BY mydate DESC;";

       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
       {
           try
           {
               dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

               conn.Open();
               cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

               DataTable dt = new DataTable();

               SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

               dt.Load(reader);

               dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

               // Add a button column. 
               DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
               buttonColumn.HeaderText = "Edit";
               buttonColumn.Name = "Status Request Name";
               buttonColumn.Text = "Edit";
               buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

               DGV_UserList.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
               return dt;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
              return null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Define a DataGridViewButtonColumn and a DataGridViewCheckBox column and add them to the columns collection

Comment: @Plutonix how about display order of these columns ?

Comment: @Plutonix i did it but now I get into another problem which is my project is multiple language so now I am not able to change the text to another language sciences it programmatically set it please is there any way to to add data from `datatable` to already exist column within my `datagridview`

Comment: `another problem` means you should post a new question.  The info in this post doest come close to whats needed for the new problem